# JSON decode on Bit2Check.com API response

Tags: php, json

I'm using the Bit2Check.com API. I want to check emails registered on PayPal. But after supplying email address to the API, I get this response:

```
{"Paypal":"Linked"}
```

I just want to grab the "Linked" part.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I m really sorry. Next time i will try it first and if i can't go through i will open post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing me with no code, so I will have to try to answer your question in general.

You probably have 
`{"Paypal" : "Linked"}`
stored within some variable. To access the "Linked" part, you need to `json_decode()` it. Code retrieving just the "Linked" string would like something like this.

```
$yourVariable = '{"Paypal" : "Linked"}';
$decoded = json_decode($yourVariable);
// Access only linked part
$onlyLinked = $decoded->Paypal;
// Or maybe you are interested in boolean value?
$isLinked = ($decoded->Paypal == "Linked") ? true : false;
```

To read more about json_decode(), visit [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on php.net.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sandy My pleasure. If this answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted (green check symbol right under the answer rating (currently 0)).